# D3 Line graph is not rendering on IE8

Tags: svg, d3.js

We are using D3 library for creating line graph in a project. It is working as expected in modern browsers inlcuding mobile devices.

We are using Aight Library (https://github.com/shawnbot/aight) for IE8 compatibility but it is still not rendering the graph.

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.

index.html :---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="aight.js"></script>
    <!-- <script>aight.browser.ie8 = true;</script> -->   
    <script src="d3.v2.js"></script>   
    <script src="d3nvtooltip.js"></script>
    <script src="d3legend.js"></script>
    <script src="d3line.js"></script>
    <script src="d3linewithlegend.js"></script>
    <script src="graph.js"></script>
    <script src="aight.d3.js"></script>
    <link href="d3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style>
#test1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: none;
}
</style>
  </head>
  <body>   
<div id="test1">
  <svg></svg>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

graph.js : ---

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var margin = {top: 30, right: 10, bottom: 50, left: 60},
      chart = d3LineWithLegend()
                .xAxis.label('xAxis')
                .width(width(margin))
                .height(height(margin))
                .yAxis.label('yAxis');

  var svg = d3.select('#test1 svg')
      .datum(generateData())

  svg.transition().duration(500)
      .attr('width', width(margin))
      .attr('height', height(margin))
      .call(chart);

  chart.dispatch.on('showTooltip', function(e) {
  var offset = $('#test1').offset(), // { left: 0, top: 0 }
        left = e.pos[0] + offset.left,
        top = e.pos[1] + offset.top,
        formatter = d3.format(".04f");
    var content = '<h3>' + e.series.label + '</h3>' +
                  '<p>' +
                  '<span class="value">[' + e.point[0] + ', ' + formatter(e.point[1]) + ']</span>' +
                  '</p>';
    nvtooltip.show([left, top], content);
  });

  chart.dispatch.on('hideTooltip', function(e) {
    nvtooltip.cleanup();
  });

  $(window).resize(function() {
    var margin = chart.margin();

    chart
      .width(width(margin))
      .height(height(margin));

    d3.select('#test1 svg')
      .attr('width', width(margin))
      .attr('height', height(margin))
      .call(chart);

    });

  function width(margin) {
    var w = 800 - 20;
    return ( (w - margin.left - margin.right - 20) < 0 ) ? margin.left + margin.right + 2 : w;
  }

  function height(margin) {
    var h = 500 - 20;
    return ( h - margin.top - margin.bottom - 20 < 0 ) ? margin.top + margin.bottom + 2 : h;
  }

  //data
  function generateData() {
    var data1 = [[1,250000],[2,249318],[3,248634],[4,247948],[5,247260],[6,246569],[7,245876],[8,245181],[9,244483],[10,243783],[11,243081],[12,242376],[13,241669],[14,240960],[15,240248],[16,239534],[17,238817],[18,238098],[19,237377],[20,236653],[21,235927],[22,235199],[23,234468],[24,233734],[25,232998],[26,232260],[27,231519],[28,230776],[29,230031],[30,229282],[31,228532],[32,227778],[33,227023],[34,226265],[35,225504],[36,224741],[37,223975],[38,223206],[39,222435],[40,221662],[41,220886],[42,220107],[43,219326],[44,218542],[45,217756],[46,216967],[47,216175],[48,215380],[49,214583],[50,213784],[51,212981],[52,212176],[53,211369],[54,210558],[55,209745],[56,208929],[57,208111],[58,207290],[59,206466],[60,205639],[61,204809],[62,203977],[63,203142],[64,202304],[65,201464],[66,200620],[67,199774],[68,198925],[69,198073],[70,197219],[71,196361],[72,195501],[73,194637],[74,193771],[75,192902],[76,192030],[77,191155],[78,190278],[79,189397],[80,188513],[81,187627],[82,186737],[83,185845],[84,184949],[85,184051],[86,183149],[87,182245],[88,181337],[89,180427],[90,179513],[91,178597],[92,177677],[93,176754],[94,175829],[95,174900],[96,173968],[97,173033],[98,172095],[99,171153],[100,170209],[101,169261],[102,168310],[103,167357],[104,166399],[105,165439],[106,164476],[107,163509],[108,162539],[109,161566],[110,160590],[111,159610],[112,158627],[113,157641],[114,156651],[115,155659],[116,154662],[117,153663],[118,152660],[119,151654],[120,150645],[121,149632],[122,148616],[123,147596],[124,146573],[125,145547],[126,144517],[127,143484],[128,142447],[129,141407],[130,140363],[131,139316],[132,138266],[133,137212],[134,136154],[135,135093],[136,134028],[137,132960],[138,131889],[139,130813],[140,129734],[141,128652],[142,127566],[143,126476],[144,125383],[145,124286],[146,123185],[147,122081],[148,120973],[149,119861],[150,118745],[151,117626],[152,116503],[153,115377],[154,114246],[155,113112],[156,111974],[157,110833],[158,109687],[159,108538],[160,107385],[161,106228],[162,105067],[163,103902],[164,102734],[165,101561],[166,100385],[167,99204],[168,98020],[169,96832],[170,95640],[171,94443],[172,93243],[173,92039],[174,90831],[175,89619],[176,88403],[177,87182],[178,85958],[179,84730],[180,83497],[181,82260],[182,81020],[183,79775],[184,78526],[185,77273],[186,76015],[187,74754],[188,73488],[189,72218],[190,70944],[191,69665],[192,68382],[193,67095],[194,65804],[195,64509],[196,63209],[197,61904],[198,60596],[199,59283],[200,57965],[201,56644],[202,55318],[203,53987],[204,52652],[205,51313],[206,49969],[207,48620],[208,47267],[209,45910],[210,44548],[211,43182],[212,41811],[213,40435],[214,39055],[215,37670],[216,36281],[217,34887],[218,33488],[219,32085],[220,30677],[221,29264],[222,27847],[223,26424],[224,24998],[225,23566],[226,22130],[227,20688],[228,19242],[229,17792],[230,16336],[231,14875],[232,13410],[233,11940],[234,10465],[235,8985],[236,7500],[237,6010],[238,4515],[239,3015],[240,1510],[241,0]];

    return [
      {
        data: data1,
        label: "Label"
      }
    ];
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation of Aight:

> Aight is a collection of shims and polyfills that get IE8 up to speed
>   with a bare minimum of HTML5 compatibility, providing all of the
>   interfaces necessary to do **HTML-only** DOM manipulation with d3.js (and
>   other libraries that rely on those interfaces)

Your graph is svg-based, so you're going to have to find another solution if you need it to render in IE8 and lower. One such possibility would be to shim the svg functionality with [R2D3](https://github.com/mhemesath/r2d3) (raphael.js for D3). That will be able to handle some cases by translating to VML (via raphaël).

Comment: I tried R2D3 as per your suggestion but still no luck.....Can you please give me any sample page so i can look into this.

Comment: R2D3 does come with a bunch of examples, did you look at them? https://github.com/mhemesath/r2d3/tree/master/examples